# What "without" means?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Is the meaning of "without" the same in the below sentences?

1. John eats his meal without a knife.
2. You can't win the lottery without a lottery ticket .

Is in the second sentence equivalent to "If you don't have a lottery ticket you can't win the lottery'?

Comment: "In the absence of"

Comment: Why do you think that they might be different?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what distinction you are trying to put your finger on. It would help if you provided all the other possible meanings of the second sentence that you think also apply but contradict the meaning that you have provided.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Suppose "A=Jonh uses a knife" and "B=John eats his meal". If we interpret without as "if not" then "If not A then B" is what the first sentence is. Suppose now that John doesn't eat his meal i.e. (B=false)  and he uses a knife (not A=false) then the first statement is vacuously true whereas if we interpret it as a conjuction i.e. "not A and B" then it is false because he doesn't eat his meal at first. What I want to say is that the interpretation of "without" depends and I want to know If I am using it correct.

Comment: @adosar The first sentence is a statement of what is happening rather than a logical statement, if it were changed to "John can eat his meal without a knife", then perhaps we can interpret that as "It is not true that without a knife John can't eat his meal" or "not (if not A, then not B)" where "A=John has a knife" and "B=John can eat his meal". This can be simplified to "not (if B, then A)" or "John being able to eat his meal does not imply that he has a knife".

Comment: As for the second sentence, it can be interpreted as "If you don't have a lottery ticket then you can't win the lottery" or "if !A, then !B" where "A=Having a lottery ticket" and "B=Able to win the lottery". That can be simplified to "if B, then A" or "If you can win the lottery, then you have a lottery ticket.".
The only difference between the two statements is the negation around the entire thing, from the "can't".

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to analyse the first sentence as two elementary propositions joined by a logical operator. The propositional calculus, however, doesn't have the tools that capture the natural-language meaning of the first sentence. *Without a knife* cannot be treated as a separate proposition, independent from the one about eating. Rather, *without a knife* modifies *eats*; one can think of the first sentence as saying something like 'John eats his meal knifelessly'.

Answer (score 1):

**Without** is the negative converse of "with". Without is used in your example as an instrumental preposition = "in the absence of"

John eats his meal **without** a knife. = John eats his meal **in the absence of** a knife.

Comment: Note, the knife itself may not be "absent", merely the *use of it* is absent in the process of eating. An exact synonym for "without" in these cases, is something like "whilst not holding", "whilst avoiding the use of", or "using means other than".

Answer (score 0):

They are the same meaning. This is also clear in alternatives such as *Not having a knife, John eats his meal* and *Not having a lottery ticket, you can't win the lottery*.

I add that *without* has another meaning, as in the hymn "*There is a green hill far away, without a city wall*". When young I wondered why a green field would need a wall (as in the above usages). But it means that the green field is positioned without (=outside) the city wall; this makes far more sense. Age sometimes brings wisdom.

Comment: The first sentence doesn't seem more like a conjuction of "John eats his meal and John doesn't use a knife to eat his meal"? Whereas "John eats his meal only if he doesn't use a knife" is not equivalent to the first statement (conjuction).

Comment: Where and why did “only” enter the discussion?

Comment: Me too also, Anton! I was getting quite grown up  before I realised that 'without' could mean 'outside'. The Scots still use it to mean 'outside' though, you sometimes hear them saying things like "people without the area" in TV interviews. I actually think that the 'outside' definition is the original. There are towns in England where 'without' is part of a location name.  Beverley in the East Riding of Yorkshire has two parts of the street that passes through the medieval North Bar gate still called North Bar Within on the town centre side and North Bar Without on the more peripheral side.

Comment: 'Not having a knife, John eats his meal' defaults to an explanatory relationship between participial clause and main clause. One might expect 'Not having a knife, John eats his meal with his hands'. A contrived context is 'All the other lads sit around the campfire arguing about who has the best Swiss Army knife. Not having a knife, John eats his meal.'